# Unhashable type list

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

We have set `S` of tuples.

Each tuple is `(string, string, list)`

Below code:

```
def f(entry_set, def_dict, S):
    for entry in entry_set:
        if entry[1] in def_dict:
            S.add((entry[0], entry[1], def_dict[entry[1]]),) // error
```

gives error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

`def_dict` was constructed with values that append list.

---

For adding an entry, Is hashing used to find the uniqueness of a set element?

Comment: Can you include some input and expected output?

Comment: Sets are effectively dictionaries without values, and dictionaries are effectively hash tables, and you can't put things in a hash table unless you can hash them.

Comment: Use tuples instead of lists.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  I cannot because i need this code: `def_dict[key].append(list_elem)`. Query edited

Comment: Is that how you *build* or how you *use* that sequence? In the former case, convert the ``list`` to a ``tuple`` when inserting it. In the later case, I am afraid that makes no sense - a ``set`` is defined via equality, which is broken by changing elements.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yup I had to convert to tuple..

Answer (score 0):

A `list` is a mutable reference so can't be hashed since it references memory. If you can convert the lists to tuples you can hash them.

```
set((1, 2, [3, 4]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d0176c73c39f> in <module>()
----> 1 set((1, 2, [3, 4]))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

As opposed to:

```
set((1, 2, (3, 4)))
{(3, 4), 1, 2}
```